# Pyspark: not cumulative sum over partition

Tags: pyspark, sum, window, partition

I would like to sum over a partition without having as a result, a cumulative sum but rather, the  whole sum on each partition:

*From*:

| Category A | Category B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 1 | 110 |
| 2 | 2 | 200 |

*I would like to have:*

| Category A | Category B | Value | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 250 |
| 1 | 2 | 150 | 250 |
| 2 | 1 | 110 | 110 |
| 2 | 2 | 200 | 200 |

*With:*

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(["Category A","Category B"])
df = df.withColumn('sum', sum(df.Value).over(windowSpec))
```

I don't obtain the result I want,I obtain the cumulative sum:

| Category A | Category B | Value | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 150 | 250 |
| 2 | 1 | 110 | 110 |
| 2 | 2 | 200 | 200 |

How could I proceed? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a window you can specify the [range](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?pyspark.sql.Window#pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween) for the window.

You can specify the range `(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)` to sum over all rows within each partition irrespective of the ordering of the rows:

```
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(["Category A","Category B"])\
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn('sum', F.sum(df.Value).over(windowSpec))\
    .orderBy("Category A", "Category B").show()
```

prints

```
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|Category A|Category B|Value|  sum|
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|         1|         2|  100|250.0|
|         1|         2|  150|250.0|
|         2|         1|  110|110.0|
|         2|         2|  200|200.0|
+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```